# Is it possible to calculate the effective shift time based on a start/end date and pauses in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I have an table in Oracle

| shift_id | timestamp_(oracle) | type_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000001 | 17/05/2022 08:00 | 0001 |
| 00000001 | 17/05/2022 09:00 | 0002 |
| 00000001 | 17/05/2022 09:15 | 0003 |
| 00000001 | 17/05/2022 12:00 | 0002 |
| 00000001 | 17/05/2022 13:00 | 0003 |
| 00000001 | 17/05/2022 15:00 | 0004 |

type 1 is starttime, type 2 is pause, type 3 is continue after pause, type 4 is end_time

I want to calculate the effective shift time, one way to do this in my opinion is to calculate the  sum of all start and end times and substract them, for example:

(sum(type 0002) + sum (type 0004)) - (sum (type 0001) + sum (type 0003))

But how to do this in oracle sql?

I've tried:
select shift_id, sum(to_number_to_char(timestamp_,'sssss') where (type_ = 0002 or type is 0004) group by shift_id

Then I get a result like
00000001, 82442
But the sum is not the right sum, it only calculates with seconds after midnight.

**Question:** How to get a result like:
00000001, 05:45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LAG window function to calculate the time differencea and thn SUM it to get the total amount -

```
CALC AS (SELECT d.*,
                EXTRACT(DAY FROM timestamp_oracle - LAG(timestamp_oracle) OVER(PARTITION BY shift_id ORDER BY timestamp_oracle)) * 24 * 60 +
                EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp_oracle - LAG(timestamp_oracle) OVER(PARTITION BY shift_id ORDER BY timestamp_oracle)) * 60 +  
                EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM timestamp_oracle - LAG(timestamp_oracle) OVER(PARTITION BY shift_id ORDER BY timestamp_oracle)) tm
  FROM data d)
  SELECT shift_id,
         TRUNC(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN type_ <> '0003' then tm else null end))/ 60) || ':' ||
         MOD(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN type_ <> '0003' then tm else null end)), 60) tot_tm
    from calc
   GROUP BY shift_id;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1aea5eee1dfb257b27b3219cefd20525)

Comment: Hello Ankit Bajpai, thank you for the answer. The demo worked perfect. Only apparently the format of the timestamps in my database is working out not as expected; I've looked up the data type and that is TIMESTAMP(6) for timestamp_(oracle). So when i run the query as supposed I'lll get an error: ORA-00932: inconsisten datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND. Do you know how to fix that as well?

Comment: @Dreqnoid, Can you please post the create table statement for your table?

Comment: Hello that's not possible because it's created by a supplier, i have database access, is there a command that i can execute?

Comment: @Dreqnoid, Please try the edited query.

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thank you for your solution, I do not fully understand what is happening here, but I'll study on that.

Comment: Hi Ankit, is it possible to include the seconds as well? Not all times in the table are with zero seconds.

Comment: @Dreqnoid, include seconds also in your data and in query along with days, hours, and minutes. You will get that in result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244823/discussion-between-ankit-bajpai-and-dreqnoid).

Answer (score 1):

Doing a LAG gives you access to the current and previous values

```
select 
  shift_id,
  typ,
  tstamp,
  lag(typ) over ( order by tstamp ) prev_typ,
  lag(tstamp) over ( order by tstamp ) prev_tstamp
from ...
```

Once you have that, then you can work out intervals as required, eg

```
select 
  shift_id,
  min(case when typ = 1 then tstamp end ) start_time
  max(case when typ = 4 then tstamp end ) end_time
  sum(case when typ in (2,4) then tstamp - prev_tstamp  end ) 
from 
  ( < above > 
group by shift_id
```

or similar depending on how you want to slice and dice